# Scanning the network traffic of a server in Java

Tags: java, api, networking

My question is: Is it possible to scan the network traffic of a server you are connected with as a client in Java. If so, how?

Comment: You can track the traffic of the server from the serverside but not as a client. At least not by legal ways. Move the question to [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/), it's to broad and off-topic here. [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) is also a good site for the question. [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) as well. *(FBI is watching you.)*